# how to get data out of `dictreader` in python

Tags: python, csv

using the following code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csvRaw = csv.dictreader(open("propertyOutput.csv",delimiter=','))
    for row in csvRaw:
        print row
```

I get the following output:

```
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]
[ nan  nan  nan  nan]...
```

there is a bunch of data, some text, some numbers that should be spit out.

data sample from csv file:

```
_id,    zip,    user_id,    name
ObjectID(525aae),   11101,  ObjectID(52389889), Property 1
ObjectID(525afec3), ca4020, ObjectID(52389d1bc5f59),    San diego beach house
```

how do I get the proper data?

Comment: Does you data file have a header row? It helps greatly if you post a sample of your data, just a few rows will do.

Comment: That doesn't look like it can be your code: the capitalization is wrong on `csv.DictReader`, so I'd have expected an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @DSM it's the magic `csv.reader` that also does type conversions and displays data as numpy arrays... ;)

Comment: See @DSM's comment about correcting the capitalisation and making it `csv.DictReader` and see how you go from there... Although it's completely baffling as to how you're getting numpy arrays at present... but the number of columns ties up I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your output can come from that code.  The Python doesn't work, and as @JonClements pointed out, the representation clearly isn't coming from the `print` you showed.  What you *should* have seen would be something like this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("propertyOutput.csv", "rb") as fp:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(fp, skipinitialspace=True)
...     for row in reader:
...         print row
...         
{'_id': 'ObjectID(525aae)', 'user_id': 'ObjectID(52389889)', 'name': 'Property 1', 'zip': '11101'}
{'_id': 'ObjectID(525afec3)', 'user_id': 'ObjectID(52389d1bc5f59)', 'name': 'San diego beach house', 'zip': 'ca4020'}
```

Comment: Should fix the problem... now... just wait for the "how do I split them" bit :)

Comment: made progress.  now i'm getting error: `  File "propertyOutput.csv", line 2
    ObjectID(525aae02763f4a86618b6248),"11101",ObjectID(523898842f00ea5fd1bc5f59),"Property 1"
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @dwstein: How did you manage to get a `SyntaxError`?   That makes it look like you're executing data somehow.

Comment: execution was jacked up.  I tried to delete the question.  sorry to waste everyone's time.